# What did I do wrong in this question?

Tags: support, specific-question

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62805456/lambda-in-stream-map-filter-not-called) about Java streams, and it got 2 downvotes, which isn't terrible, but still confusing. There are no close votes or comments about what I did wrong, and in my (probably biased) opinion, it's a great question, since I've put in the output I expected, the output I got, and the code I used.

I wrote the question because it seems to be a common mistake to leave out terminal operations in streams (I and people I know have made this mistake a few times before, and I saw a similar question), and I was hoping someone would post a good, canonical answer so that people wouldn't have to waste time looking for the answer to their problem if they didn't know that streams had to be terminated.

Is there any way I can edit the question to make it better? I certainly can't delete it now, as there are multiple upvoted answers, one of whom I've accepted. I doubt it'll get much attention on Stack Overflow now that I've accepted an answer, so I decided to ask here. Let me know if I can do something to improve this (current) question or the other one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a reason for downvote: the post *does not show research*.

Indeed you can claim "There may be other questions similar to this, but I'm looking for a kind of canonical answer" is demonstrating research, but it is in no way different from more common "searched alot", "googled on netflix and found nothing", "spend 20 days searching". Neither of these indicate that author actually spend any time researching the question and just typed those in.

The question itself looks like it should be asked thousands of times<sup>*</sup> (at least the same on in C# is asked almost daily). If you actually don't understand the reason after reading all similar question the question should be worded differently - and definitely link to existing posts with explanation what you don't get. If the whole reason of posting is to get a canonical answer to be written *by someone else* and you don't really need this question... you probably should have add bounty some existing question instead.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>I have no experience with Java and indeed this could be new and unique question from Java point of view... but based on some cursory search the features are there for several years and usage is way too basic to newer hit by anyone.</sub>

Comment: Your suggestion that I should have added a bounty to an existing question is valid, but I found similar questions very hard to find. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62350256/put-method-not-called-in-stream-map) one that I have a link to because I answered it, and I only ever found a couple more related questions. You're absolutely right that this isn't a brand-new API (or an obscure one), but it's still hard to find questions like that, so I figured I'd make a catch-all question.

Comment: @user SEO is hard... If you believe you nailed the question you still could have marked it as duplicate or self answer like James_D suggest - making others do that work so you can collect upvotes on the question when you could have done it yourself does not reflect well on the post.

Comment: Note that if you are confident that you nailed the SEO for the question initial downvotes for "no research" don't really matter... (whether it aligns with SO goals of upvotes or not).

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure why the question attracted downvotes; I agree that it is a well-posed question. However, if your intention is to write a question to which you know the answer, for the purposes of providing a general "catch-all" answer that can be used as a duplicate for other similar questions, the appropriate process is to answer the question yourself.

When posting a new question, there is an "Answer your own question" checkbox, which will allow you to compose the answer and post both the question and answer together. This will make it immediately clear to users the purpose of your Question and Answer.

If you are ok with forgoing the reputation earned from the answer, you can also mark the answer as a "Community Wiki". This would indicate an intention that other users would be encouraged to edit and improve your answer.

Comment: You're right, I should probably have done that, but I wasn't sure my answer would be good enough, so I just decided to hope for an expert to come along and answer. I'll keep this in mind next time